# How to write a C++ wrapper for C in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, wrapper

I have added libstdc++ to the linker options, but I keep getting an "undefined reference" to all C++ functions that I want to use in C.

I think the problem is that the files in question are not compiled using g++, but how do I define this rule in Eclipse?

Comment: You want to call C++ functions from C code?

Comment: Yup :) I can probably make it work using the basic compiler commands, but I would like it to work in Eclipse.

Comment: The only way to do that is to compile your code with a C++ compiler and just write the other code in a subset of C++. No C compiler can handle templates.

Answer (score 1):

To make a C++ function callable from C++, you must - at a minimum - use "extern C {}":

- http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

You cannot invoke any C++ only constructs (like new, delete, any classes or any templates) from a C program - your C module won't compile and/or won't link.

You *should* be able to compile legal C modules that have a .c suffix with Eclipse and/or from the g++ command line.

Answer (score 0):

One way to use g++ to compile, is to select C file in project explorer, select C/C++ build, Settings, and enter g++ into a command field. There probably is some cleaner way, but it should work...